# Passing data from Activity to Fragment in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-fragments

I have just started Android and i am working on Simple Login Page,where user can use their email and password to login with some conditions while login. When user login as a "store owner",his name and email is shown on the next page (i.e on the Fragment class) which is working fine but whenever user login as a "public user",his name and email is not showing on the next page.

Note: I am using webservices and SharedPreferences to fetch and save data.

Thanks in Advance

Here is my code

LoginActivity

```
   public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText login_emailid, login_password;
    String str_login_email, str_login_password;
    Button login_button;


    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAMEs = "MyPrefsFiles";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        login_emailid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_emailid);
        login_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        login_button.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == login_button) {

                    str_login_email = login_emailid.getText().toString();
                    str_login_password = login_password.getText().toString();

                    if (str_login_email.isEmpty()) {
                        login_emailid.setError("Enter your email");
                    } else if (str_login_password.isEmpty()) {
                        login_password.setError("Password Please");
                    } else {
                        new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
                    }

                }
            }

    }

    public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        return !(email == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
    public String connection(String action) {
        String result = "";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://beta.gkninternational.life/webservice/user_login.php");// replace with your url
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                "action", action));

        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                "Email", str_login_email));
        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                "Password", str_login_password));

        try {
            Log.e("nameValuePairList", " " + nameValuePairList);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                    nameValuePairList);
            httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient
                        .execute(httpPost);
                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                        .getContent();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }
                result = stringBuilder.toString();
                Log.e("result", stringBuilder.toString());

                return stringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                System.out
                        .println("First Exception coz of HttpResponese :"
                                + cpe);
                cpe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out
                        .println("Second Exception coz of HttpResponse :"
                                + ioe);
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
            uee.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog mProgressBar;
        String resp;
        int success;
        String message;

        String name, email, password, userrole, userpic, iddd;
        String storeId,storeName;

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesLogin;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = connection("Login_Activity");
            try {

                sharedPreferencesLogin = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAMEs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = sharedPreferencesLogin.edit();

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
                message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                    iddd = jsonObject.getString("UserId");
                name = jsonObject.getString("FirstName");
                email = jsonObject.getString("Email");
                userrole = jsonObject.getString("UserRole");
                storeId = jsonObject.getString("StoreId");
                storeName = jsonObject.getString("StoreName");

                editor.putString("UserId", name);
                editor.putString("FirstName", name);
                editor.putString("Email", email);
                editor.putString("userrole", userrole);
                editor.putString("storeIdLogin", storeId);
                editor.putString("StoreNameLogin", storeName);
                editor.apply();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resp;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            mProgressBar.dismiss();

            if (success == 2) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (success == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(userrole.equals("store_owner"))
                {
                    if(storeName.equals("Dummy")){
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EditActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                    else{
                        Intent intentt = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intentt);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Intent intentuser = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AfterSplash.class);
                    startActivity(intentuser);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            mProgressBar.setMessage("Connecting to server");

            mProgressBar.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressBar.show();
        }
}
```

Frament class

public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesLogin;
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAMEs = "MyPrefsFiles";
TextView names,emails;

String str_names,str_emails;

public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);


    sharedPreferencesLogin=    getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAMEs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    names=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.names);
    emails=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.emails);

    str_names=     sharedPreferencesLogin.getString("FirstName","");
    str_emails=      sharedPreferencesLogin.getString("Email","");

    names.setText(str_names);
    emails.setText(str_emails);

}
```

}

Comment: get ur sharedpreference value in activity public static variable and in fragment class call it by activities reference  Activity.variable in your fragment

Comment: Use bundle for fragment

Answer (score 2):

try this to set Shared Pref

```
String userId=yourstring;
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(youractivity.this);
            Editor edit = settings.edit();
            edit.putString("name", userId);
            settings.commit;
```

to get shared pref

```
SharedPreferences settins = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Youractivity.this);
name=settings.getString("name", "anon");
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `newInstance()` method in your fragment like this.

```
public static YourFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {

    ActivityFeedListFragment fragment = new ActivityFeedListFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

And pass `bundle` object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a bundle and a serializable object to pass.:

- From the **activity**:

> ```
> Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
> Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
> bundle.putSerializable(ARGUMENT_KEY, objectSerializable);
> fragment.setArguments(bundle); showFragment(fragment)
> ```

- On the **fragment**:

> ```
> Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
> if (bundle != null) {
> Object neededObject = bundle.getSerializable(ser_key)
> }
> ```